# It is giving error 401 and my hyper is pointing out the temp variable as the problem. any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, json

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){
    const query = req.body.cityname;
    const apikey = "be542b6232b2bc2d159d89e25bf419fc";
    const unit = "metric";
    const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q= " + query + "&appid= " + apikey + "&units= " + unit;
    https.get(url, function(response){
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        response.on("data", function(data){
            const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
            const temp = weatherData.main.temp;
            const weatherDescription = weatherData.weather[0].description;
            const icon = weatherData.weather[0].icon;
            const imageURL = "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + "@2x.png";
            res.write("<p>The weather is currently " + weatherDescription + " </p>");
            res.write("<h1>The temperature in " + query + " is " + temp + " degree celsius.</h1>");
            res.write("<img src = " + imageURL + ">");
            res.send();
        });
    });
});
app.listen(1500, function(){
    console.log("Server is running on port 1500");
});
```

Comment: Hyper? Temp variable? Please include the exact error message and the data you’re operating on.

Comment: My hyper terminal is giving a 401 error and is pointing out the "temp" variable which is actually the temperature to be undefined. even though i have copied the whole code from angela yu's course yet its giving an error.

Comment: Without knowing what the data is there’s no way to know why a property might be undefined.

Comment: @AmnaIftikhar Please include the exact error message you're seeing in the terminal. Besides, by Hyper, do you mean Hyper terminal? These details might help.

Comment: 401 is Unauthorized ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401

Comment: no need for the spaces here: `const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q= " + query + "&appid= " + apikey + "&units= " + unit;` after those `=` signs

Comment: `src = "` that space will cause issues.  Consider wrapping in single quotes right before and after that variables insertion inside the double quotes  Example: `res.write("<img src='" + imageURL + "'>");`

Comment: 45000 people just used your API key...oh darn, you exceeded its use perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the 401 error could be related to how you are forming the URL for the OpenWeatherMap API. Make sure there are no extra spaces in the URL, and the API key is appended correctly. Also, ensure that the city name is correctly received from the request.

Here is a modified version of your code:

```js
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  const query = req.body.cityname;
  const apikey = "be542b6232b2bc2d159d89e25bf419fc";
  const unit = "metric";

  // Ensure there are no extra spaces in the URL
  const url =
    "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +
    query +
    "&appid=" +
    apikey +
    "&units=" +
    unit;

  https.get(url, function (response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);

    let data = "";

    response.on("data", function (chunk) {
      data += chunk;
    });

    response.on("end", function () {
      try {
        const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);

        if (weatherData.cod === "404") {
          // Handle case when city is not found
          res.send("<h1>City not found. Please try again.</h1>");
          return;
        }

        const temp = weatherData.main.temp;
        const weatherDescription = weatherData.weather[0].description;
        const icon = weatherData.weather[0].icon;
        const imageURL =
          "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + "@2x.png";

        res.write("<p>The weather is currently " + weatherDescription + " </p>");
        res.write(
          "<h1>The temperature in " + query + " is " + temp + " degree celsius.</h1>"
        );
        res.write("<img src=" + imageURL + ">");
        res.send();
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle JSON parsing error
        console.error("Error parsing JSON:", error);
        res.send("<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>");
      }
    });
  });
});

app.listen(1500, function () {
  console.log("Server is running on port 1500");
});
```

Changes made:

1. Used the `response.on("end", ...)` event to wait for the complete response data.
2. Checked for a 404 response from the OpenWeatherMap API to handle cases where the city is not found.
3. Removed extra spaces in the URL concatenation.
4. Added error handling for JSON parsing errors.

Please try this modified code and see if it resolves the issue. If the problem persists, you may want to check the OpenWeatherMap API documentation and verify the correct usage of the API key and parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention that you've 'have copied the whole code from angela yu's course', it's likely that the API key being used is no longer valid, hence you're getting a response with 401 status.

See this for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401

To fix this, you would have to generate new API key for api.openweathermap.org/